# Correct postgres lock for preventing duplicate inserts

Tags: postgresql, locking, knex.js

### Explanation of problem

Consider a `rewards` table, which has a `type` column, one of whose possible values is `ONE_PER_PERSON`.

There is also a `redeemed_rewards` link table, for keeping track of which rewards have been redeemed by which users.  It has two columns: `user_id` and `reward_id`.

Now consider a high-level function responsible for the business logic that redeems a reward.  The function's signature looks like this:

```
function redeemReward(userId, rewardId)
```

Specifically, consider the case where a `ONE_PER_PERSON` reward is being redeemed.  At a high-level, the function's logic for this case looks like:

1. Start a transaction
2. Query to ensure that the reward has not previously been redeemed by this user.  That is, ensure the following query returns a count of 0:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM redeemed_rewards 
   WHERE user_id = ${userId} AND reward_id = ${rewardId}
   ```
3. Assuming it has not, insert the redeemed reward:

   ```
   INSERT INTO redeemed_rewards VALUES (${userId}, ${rewardId})
   ```
4. Commit the transaction

The problem with this logic is that it's vulnerable to race conditions.  Since the function can theoretically be called by multiple threads, it's conceivable that 2 threads can both bypass step 2, each before the other has reached step 4, resulting in two inserted records, and thus violating the `ONE_PER_PERSON` constraint.

### Question

I think the correct solution is to lock the table from inserts at step 1, and keep it locked until step 4.

My questions are:

1. What is the appropriate postgres lock for this situation?  Ideally, I could lock against *inserts containing the specified userId only*, so that other users are unaffected.  However, I don't believe this is possible.  So which type of table lock should I be using?
2. Bonus question: How can implment this lock in a knex query?  The docs don't seem to mention anything about locks...

### PLEASE NOTE

A unique index is not a viable solution for me here.  Not all types of rewards are one per user.  Also, I specifically want to understand postgres locking and how to use it properly in situations where it is needed.

Comment: If it only can redeem one unique per user, why don't you have a unique index for it and just try to insert it? Then Postgres would take care of locking implicitly for that row, I think.

Comment: Create a unique index and deal with the error.

Comment: Before thinking about locks, define the constraints. It helps.

Comment: A unique index won't work here.  Only some types of rewards are one per user.  Others are not.  I specifically put that info in the question for that reason.

Comment: actually a unique index is possible.  But you can also go a row lock approach if you want (though this assumes some things a good dba may not want to assume)

Comment: You can create partial unique indexes for those types that must be unique

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The `WHERE` clause on a partial index needs to be immutable; not an option here, since the condition depends on the contents of another table.

Comment: @NickBarnes: `create unique index on redeemed_rewards (user_id) where reward_id = 1` (assuming that `ONE_PER_PERSON` has the id 1)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but that would require as many unique indexes as `ONE_PER_PERSON` typed rows in the `rewards` table.

Comment: @a_horse: Likely impractical to recreate the index every time the table changes. And in any case, bad practice to keep multiple copies of this information without some process to keep them in sync. Though it would work if you kept a trigger-maintained copy of `rewards.type` in the `redeemed_rewards` table.

Comment: @pozs: correct, but that still is a more robust (and scalable) solution that doing manual locking

Comment: @Jonah the main question for using locks vs. using (partial) unique indexes (like in Chris' answer): What should happen, if a row in the `rewards` table is updated from non-`ONE_PER_PERSON` to `ONE_PER_PERSON` typed? Can it happen?

Comment: @pozs yes that can happen

Comment: @Jonah then locking is not really an option here. Only unique index(es) will provide enough data consistency.

Comment: @pozs it would not be retroactive.  also the unique index discussion is a red herring imo.  it won't handle TWO_PER_PERSON type, eg.

Answer (score 9):

This presents a problem because duplicate inserts are a bit hard to prevent without some sort of explicit locking.

The first option would be to use the reward id or user as a semaphor, to effectively serialize all your writes to a specific user or reward id.  In that way you do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM reward WHERE id = ? FOR UPDATE;
```

Then every attempt to redeem the same reward will wait for other attempts to go through first.  You could do the same with user instead depending on your traffic approach.  Then when the transaction completes, the lock is released.

This works by locking rows in reward for the transaction.  The main advantage here is that it is simple.  The main disadvantage is that only your application is covered for the ability to serialize reads in this way.

In this way many people can redeem different reward ids at once, but for each reward id, it will lock the row in the rewards table and wait block others from doing the same until it commits.

The second approach would be to use advisory locks.  There are some advantages here but there are also some drawbacks, so I would look at that (and spend some time with the documentation) if row locks won't do what you need.

Edit:

Actually a unique index is possible, but to do it you have to rethink your database a little bit.  As you mentioned the `(user_id, reward_id)` combo is unique for certain reward types.

So what you need to do is create a unique index on the reward table for `reward_id, reward_type` and then add reward_type to your foreign key in your redeemed_rewards table.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX redeemed_rewards_only_one_per_user 
    ON redeemed_rewards (user_id, reward_id) 
 WHERE reward_type = 'ONE_PER_USER`
```

Then PostgreSQL will throw an error when only these types of rewards are redeemed more than once.  This has the advantage of having the logic directly enforced by the db, so you don't have to worry about messing things up with a stray query or administrative action.

Comment: `pg_advisory_xact_lock(user_id, reward_id)` is definitely the easiest way out of this, though as you said, advisory locks need to be used carefully. [`SERIALIZABLE` transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) also deserve a mention here.

Comment: The big problem with advisory locks is that you have the issue of namespaces.  So if you go that route you effectively foreclose using advisory locks for things other than this.  It may be easy but it is not strategically cheap.

Comment: Personally I think  the partial unique index is the cleanest solution.

Comment: can you elaborate on the  first option?  how does the select for update on "reward" prevent the insertion into "redeemed_rewards"?  this solution seems promising for my use cases but I want to make sure I understand it and any possible drawbacks?  unique index doesn't provide the flexibility i need (eg, N-per-person rewards)

Comment: added.  Note you could use users instead of rewards if that scales better.

Comment: Thank you.  Upvoted.  I think this is the correct solution for me.  Indeed, you said "the main disadvantage is that only your application is covered," but I think that's a feature for my use-case, not a bug.  Eg, we might want an admin tool that allows us to override one per person and give one user an extra reward.  To be clear: if rewardid 13134 is locked by the `FOR UPDATE`, could an statement with hardcoded values like `INSERT INTO rewards VALUES (2342, 13134)` still execute during the lock?  or does the lock merely prevent the value from being read?

Comment: The lock is held until the transaction is committed.

Comment: im still not clear *what* exactly is locked?  would you mind addressing the example from my last comment?

Comment: The rows selected `for update` are locked for the duration of the transaction.  You are using row locks in one table as a semaphore to prevent race conditions.

Comment: How does `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` work when the row does not already exist? From my reading of the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) this only locks against `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, etc. `INSERT` is not listed.